# How Boolean operators fit with tags?

Tags: support, tags, search

I'm aware that if I want to search for a tag, I just type "[~~~]" in the search bar (just replace the tildes with the tag you want). But what if I want to include other things with it? How would the Boolean operators `AND` or `OR` fit with the tag?

For example, if I want to search for all posts with the `windows-8` tag that contain the word *explorer*, would I have to type "[windows-8] AND explorer" or could I just type "[windows-8] explorer"?

Answer (score 3):

The `OR` operator is used combine the results from searching multiple tags.

There does not appear to be an `AND` operator.

`[windows-8] and explorer` gives 1054 results for SuperUser.

`[windows-8] explorer` gives 1295 results.

---

[How do I search?](https://superuser.com/help/searching)

> If you need to refine and narrow your search, here are some basic tips:
>
> To search within specific tag(s), enter them in square brackets: [maintenance] seat searches for mentions of "seat" within the [maintenance] tag.

...

> OR operator
>
> To combine results from multiple tags, separate the tag names (enclosed in square brackets) with the word "or": [widgets] or [geegaws] returns questions tagged with either tag.

Comment: Yeah, haha, I know what the `OR` operator is for; I just used the example I gave as that: an example.

Comment: And really? No `AND` operator?

Comment: So `[windows-8] explorer` is indeed just the equivalent of the `AND` operator? It would do the same?

Comment: Also, am I misunderstanding the exerpt you included, or does the `OR` tag not require all caps like, say, a Google search would?

Comment: No. `or` is fine ;)

Comment: `[windows-8] explorer` is not the same as including `and`. See the answer. Number of results is different. It look like including `and` means the literal word `and` **not** an AND operator.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22388/why-or-operator-by-default-in-search